# C# string.split variances

Tags: c#

I have probably missed something very basic but this has me stumped.

When using String.Split() I get different results between

```
.Split(' ')
```

and

```
.Split(new char[' '])
```

Given this code:

```
using (System.IO.StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(@"C:\consoleapp1.log", true))
{
    string anystring = "pagelength=60 pagewidth=170 cpi=16 lpi=8 landscape=1 lm=2";
    sw.WriteLine(".Split(' ')");
    string[] anystrings1 = anystring.Split(' ');
    for (int i = 0; i < anystrings1.Length; i++)
    {
        sw.WriteLine($@"{i,2}: {anystrings1[i]}");
    }
    sw.WriteLine(".Split(new char[' '])");
    string[] anystrings2 = anystring.Split(new char[' ']);
    for (int i = 0; i < anystrings2.Length; i++)
    {
        sw.WriteLine($@"{i,2}: {anystrings2[i]}");
    }

}
```

Why do I get different results:

```
.Split(' ')
 0: pagelength=60
 1: pagewidth=170
 2: cpi=16
 3: lpi=8
 4: landscape=1
 5: lm=2
.Split(new char[' '])
 0: pagelength=60 pagewidth=170 cpi=16 lpi=8 landscape=1 lm=2
```

Comment: I think you meant to do `new char[]{' '}` for the second one

Answer (score 46, accepted):

```
new char[' ']
```

does not do what you think it does.

Space is [ASCII character 32](http://www.asciitable.com/) (and C# allows implicit conversions between `char` and `int`). So that code creates an **array** of `char` with size of 32.

Comment: Might be worth pointing out the reason - there is an implicit conversion between `char` and `int`

Comment: This mistake is so hard to spot isn't it? They should've made a character not implicitly convertible to an int. :)

Comment: I would posit that a strongly typed language like C# should not support implicit conversions at all. I agree with you on this one @Sweeper

Comment: @sweeper: There was considerable debate about whether char should go to int implicitly or not during the C# 1 design process. There was a strong desire to make C# familiar to users of C and C++, which allow chars to be treated as integers, despite "gotchas" like the one in this question. Fortunately, ints -- even constants -- are not implicitly convertible to char. I agree that, knowing what we know now about how people write C#, that making the conversion explicit would have been the better choice. These decisions are a lot easier with hindsight!